# How to find the two maximum values of a column

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a table in SAS and I'm trying to find the maximum and the second maximum value of a given column.

For example:

```
Id Column
1  100
2  50000
3  50 
4  4000
5  97
6  7000
```

My code need to find this:

```
Id Column
2   50000
6   7000
```

Is there any way to do that in `proc sql` (or even in SAS language)?

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no ties, sort the table in descending order and then take the top 2 values.

```
proc sort data=have out=temp;
by descending column;
run;

data want;
set temp(obs=2);
run;
```

If you have ties and only want the distinct values try the `nodupkey` option on PROC SORT:

```
proc sort data=have out=temp nodupkey;
by descending column;
run;

data want;
set temp(obs=2);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PROC UNIVARIATE` will do this for you, as is explained in [the documentation for the proc](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/67528/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_examples03.htm):

```
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var height;
  id name;
run;
```

Look at the `Extreme Observations` table.

If you want it in a dataset, you just use the `extremeobs` output object:

```
ods output extremeobs=extremes;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var height;
  id name;
run;
ods output close;
```

Then filter to the `high` variable and the 4th and 5th observation.  This has the same concern with ties of almost any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: `PROC MEANS` using `IDGROUP`.  This gets you a horizontal/wide dataset, but you can transpose it however you want using `PROC TRANSPOSE` or the data step.  See the paper [Transposing Data Using PROC SUMMARY'S IDGROUP Option](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/102-2010.pdf) for more details.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
  var height;
  output out=classout idgroup(max(height) out[2]  (height name)=height name) /autoname;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here's a `proc sql` solution.  Not necessarily better than any of the others and doesn't cope with ties.

```
data have;
input Id Column;
datalines;
1  100
2  50000
3  50 
4  4000
5  97
6  7000
;
run;

proc sql outobs=2;
create table want as
select * from have
order by column desc;
quit;
```

And finally, a solution using `proc rank` that does include ties

```
data have;
input Id Column;
datalines;
1  100
2  50000
3  50000 
4  4000
5  97
6  7000
;
run;

proc rank data=have out=want_ties (where=(column_rank<=2)) descending ties=dense;
var column;
ranks column_rank;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different `proc sql` option - this one selects the two highest distinct values, and all IDs with those values.  It's a bit convoluted, and only works because SAS is nice about handling summary statistics.

```
proc sql;
  select age, name
    from sashelp.class
    where age =
      (select max(age) from sashelp.class)
      or age = 
      (select max(age) from 
       (select case when age=max(age) then . else age end as age from sashelp.class)
      )
    ;
quit;
```